# Pass an image between two already loaded view controllers

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview

This may be trivial, but I'm new to Swift and would appreciate any help.

App is designed to modify images.

I have 3 ViewControllers:

- Contains UIScrollView

  - Action - All action is done to images (contained within UIScrollView)
  - Preview - Image preview (contained within UIScrollView)

I want to move a UIImage from Action to Preview.

All of the view controllers are already open. Action and Preview are side by side children of the UIScrollView. I don't want to open them again or move to them automatically. I just want to update the image in Preview after modifications are completed within Action.

I'm using Swift 3.0 and Xcode 8.

[image: Interface Builder Layout Image]

Comment: Correct me me if i understood your question wrongly,
Action and Preview are two view controller, you are previewing your image in preview controller and after preview you want to move the image to Action view controller. Is that what you want?

Comment: A picture of your current IB design might help with understanding what you need.

Comment: 2 ways are there you can use prepare for segue to pass image to the viewcontroller. Or you can use a singleton class to hold image.

Comment: @michael I have attached my IB design for you to take a look at.

Comment: @Janmenjaya I want to move my image from Action -> Preview. But I am assuming the process would be the same either way.

Comment: @vinodh I have attempted to use prepare for segue. I run into problems because it opens up a new instance of preview on top of everything else. I want to update the preview view controller which is already open.

Comment: Create a `.refreshImage(UIImage)` method in your PreviewViewController, and call it from ActionViewController.

Comment: Are you manually presenting those view controller ? how you are showing action and preview . Still confusing with storyboard image

Answer (score 0):

Normally there is only one viewController visible at a time, so assuming this is the case, the typical way to communicate between them is a property on the destination, and often this is done through a separate protocol. For example,

```
protocol CanDisplayImage {
    var imageToDisplay: UIImage? { get; set; }
}
```

Then your destination viewController would implement this protocol:

```
class MyPreviewController: UIViewController, CanDisplayImage {
    var imageToDisplay: UIImage?
    func viewDidLoad() {
        theImageView.image = imageToDisplay
    }
}
```

And then your source viewController causes a segue to the destination, and sets this property in its

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let dest = segue.destination as? CanDisplayImage {
        dest.imageToDisplay = theImageToPreview
    }
}
```

How you choose to cause the segue can be done in different ones. The most common is to ctrl-drag from a button or whatever within the source viewController to anywhere within the destination viewController.

Note that I have not checked the above code actually compiles, so I might have some typos.